# Is there any way to use contructor injection using Autofac in a Xamarin.Android project?

Tags: xamarin.android, autofac, xamarin

I'm throwing on a Xamarin.Android version of an existing app built heavily on the Microsoft stack (W8/WP8/Silverlight etc..) and Autofac is used extensively throughout.

Autofac prefers showing dependencies through constructor parameters, which of course assumes I, the coder, have control of the creation of my ViewModels/Controllers, or in Android's case... Activities.

My question is: Is there any way I can use Autofac in the desired way considering Android framework is responsible for Activity creation? Is there something I can do to intercept Activity creation to resolve the dependencies the way Autofac is designed?

Comment: I have no experience what so ever with Monodroid, but isn't there something like an `ActivityFactory`. Did you look in the source code to see how the framework creates new activities?

Comment: AndroidFactory is not a public interface.  And if it were, I'm still looking for something that I, the developer, has access to from the framework that allows me to control the instantiation of Activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to subclass Activity, and mark dependencies with a custom attribute on writable properties.

Then we can use reflection to yank those properties out and inject them using Autofac. This does *not* follow Autofac's convention of marking dependencies in constructors, but it gets the job done and injects properties somewhat like MEF does.

```
public class AutofacActivity : Activity
{
    private static ContainerBuilder ContainerBuilder { get; set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        // Bootstrap
        if (Core.IoC.Container == null) {
            new Bootstrapper ().Bootstrap ();
        }

        PropertyInfo[] properties =
            this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);            

        foreach (var property in properties.Where(p=>p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectAttribute), false).Any())) {

            object instance = null;
            if (!Core.IoC.Container.TryResolve (property.PropertyType, out instance)) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException ("Could not resolve type " + property.PropertyType.ToString ());
            }

            property.SetValue (this, instance);
        }
    }
}
```

This method works, but feels a little dirty.   Any improvements I could make?